# Microsoft Teams notification stops working intermittently

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, microsoft-teams

We have integrated MS Teams with Azure DevOps using below:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/integrations/microsoft-teams?view=azure-devops

Pipelines have been subscribed to send notifications on failure. However they stop working randomly. We are unable to identify where the problem is. Could someone guide me on how to troubleshoot the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a troubleshoot advice:

Please go to your Project Settings -> General/Service hooks and check the sevice hook to Microsoft Teams.

If you find that the notification was failed to send, it will usually provide an error message for further investigation.

If you find that it doesn't send notifications when the pipeline fails, it is recommended to check your connection settings. And identify the scope of the problem, such as whether this problem is related to a particular pipeline.

If you find that the notification has been successfully sent but the Microsoft Teams have not received it, you can further check if the intermittent problem is time related. For example, whether the problem can be repeated over a certain period of time and whether there is a significant delay between the successful notification sent time and the actual delivery time.

Comment: Thanks Jane for your response! Few more questions: What minimum permissions are required on Azure DevOps(apart from Project Amin) to enable Teams notification? Does Third party application access via oauth needs to be enabled permanently to communicated with Teams? Is it possible to enable it just for configuration and then disable it?

Comment: Hello @SQLPRODDBA, users must be in the **Project Administrators group** to set Azure Pipelines subscription with Microsoft Teams. I don't think the user needs any additional permissions other than administrator. I'm not sure I understand your second question. I work on DevOps and don't know much about Teams.

Comment: Is it possible to grant any custom role in Azure Devops which is just enough to setup notifications rather than giving project administrator role?

Comment: @SQLPRODDBA **Team administrator** can also setup notifications.  But there are two restrictions. First, Team Administrators can't remove or modify subscriptions that are created by Project Administrators. Second, Team Administrators can't unsubscribe pipeline.